# Python configparser will not accept keys without values

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

So I'm writing a script that reads from a config file, and I want to use it exactly how configparser is designed to be used as outlined here: http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.1/library/configparser.html

I am using Python 3.2.1. The script, when complete, will run on a Windows 2008 R2 machine using the same version of Python, or assuming compatibility, the latest version at the time.

```
#!/user/bin/env python
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('c:\exclude.ini')
config.sections()
```

That works fine to read the exclude.ini file - unless I have a value without a key. Thinking I might be doing something wrong tried parsing the example listed here: http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.1/library/configparser.html#supported-ini-file-structure

It still throws the following every time:

```
File "C:\Python32\lib\configparser.py", line 1081, in _read
    raise e
configparser.ParsingError: Source contains parsing errors: c:\exclude.ini
    [line 20]: 'key_without_value\n'
```

I'm at a loss... I'm literally copy/pasting the example code from the documentation for the exact python version I'm using and it's not working as it should. I can only assume I'm missing something as I also can't really find anyone with a similar issue.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [ConfigParser constructor](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.1/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser) has a keyword argument `allow_no_value` with a default value of `False`.

Try setting that to true, and I'm betting it'll work for you.

Comment: Excellent, thankyou Karl. Perhaps I should send them a note suggesting changing their example .ini to put a comment above that section noting that part only works if the constructor is changed. I suppose I should have read the entire documentation, but the way things were set out it looked to me like it should have worked like this by default.

Comment: This even works if the section looks like this:

    [Software]
    3700 Journal Copy 1.0.2
    Adobe Flash Player 11 ActiveX
    Adobe Reader X (10.1.7) - Deutsch
    DotNet Framework 4.0
    [...]

Comment: For more recent features of configparser, check the latest [python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser). `allow_no_value` is still available. OP specified that (s)he uses python 3.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

```
class RawConfigParser:
def __init__(self, defaults=None, dict_type=_default_dict,
             allow_no_value=False):
    self._dict = dict_type
    self._sections = self._dict()
    self._defaults = self._dict()
    if allow_no_value:
        self._optcre = self.OPTCRE_NV
    else:
        self._optcre = self.OPTCRE
    if defaults:
        for key, value in defaults.items():
            self._defaults[self.optionxform(key)] = value
```

import ConfigParser

cf = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)