# How to read all words under a section in configparser?

Tags: python, configparser

I'm reading from a file which has a section structured like this:

```
[name]
John
Mary
Ben
John
```

Note that there are no keys.

How to read those values with ConfigParser?

Thanks

Comment: May I ask why do you use an ini file for that and not a JSON or a YAML?

Comment: It was assigned.

Comment: What have you tried and how is it failing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python configparser will not accept keys without values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491521/python-configparser-will-not-accept-keys-without-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your `ConfigParser` with the keyword argument `allow_no_value` set to `True`. Also you need to remove the duplication in your file (John appears twice).

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.read("config_file_name")

for name in config["name"]:
    print(name)
```

Output:

```
John
Mary
Ben
```

If you need the duplications in the `name` section, you will have to inherit the `ConfigParser` class and override that limitation.

---

#### Side note:

Consider using a JSON or YAML instead of an ini file for such task, it will make your life **much** easier